# MySQL: select all rows where just the name is distinct

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I'm currently trying to select unique entries in only the name column. I have tried using this query but it will not return prices that are the same as well. I've tried other variations with no success either.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, price from table;
```

Here's the table I'm working with:

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | name      | price |
+----+-----------+-------+
| 1  | Henry     | 20    |
| 2  | Henry     | 30    |
| 3  | Robert    | 20    |
| 4  | Joshua    | 10    |
| 5  | Alexander | 30    |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

The output that I'm seeking is:

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | name      | price |
+----+-----------+-------+
| 1  | Henry     | 20    |
| 3  | Robert    | 20    |
| 4  | Joshua    | 10    |
| 5  | Alexander | 30    |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

The desired output as you can tell only removed the duplicate name and none of the prices. Is there something I can add to my query above to only select unique entries in the name column? Any help is really appreciated as I have tried to find a solution on here, Google, DuckDuckGo, etc. with no luck.

Comment: Do you care which row is returned? Which ID/price pair?

Answer (score 0):

From your sample data, this should work.

```
SELECT MIN(Id) AS Id, name, MIN(price) AS price 
FROM table
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: The result of this is going to be extremely misleading (i.e. wrong) if the row with the lowest number does not have the lowest price. I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what `GROUP BY` is for:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `name`
```

Usually people [run into trouble](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) because they will now get an *arbitrarily-chosen row* when more than one matches for a given name — you have to use aggregate functions to pick a specific one, e.g. "the one with the maximum price".

But in your case, since you don't seem to care which row is returned, this is perfect as-is.

Answer (score 0):

So you want  to select distinct list of rows AND then select that given entire row from the table? Try this query where temporary query is just a list of uniqueid then that row is linked back to the table.

```
Select n.*
From nameprices n
Join (Select MIN(id) as id
  From nameprices
  Group by name
  Order By id) aTemp On (aTemp.id=n.id);
```

This is a common problem in SQL queries where we want to use that given fully row data but filter was using a distinct/groupby formula.